# CSS Animation of class on Submit button click

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I am trying to add an animation to this web page that slides the login rectangle across the page. So from 564px to 100%. I've been able to do it with pure CSS animation, however, i dont want it to play until the submit button has been pressed in the form. Is there a way to do this? My code is below.

**HTML**

```
    <div class="innerRect">
    <br />
    <br />
    <img src="img/logo.png" />
    <br />
    <br />
    <br />
    <form id="logForm" action="" method="post">
        <p style="text-align:left; margin-left:80px;">USERNAME<br>
        <input type="text" name="username" style="width: 400px;">
    <br />
    <br />
        PASSWORD<br>
        <input type="password" name="password" style="width: 400px;">
    <br />
    <br />
        <input type="submit" value="LOG ON" style="float:right; margin-right: 85px;">
    </form>
    </p>

    <div class="settingsHelp">
    <a><img src="img/settings.png" /></a><br>
    <a><img src="img/help.png" /></a>
    </div>

    </div>
```

**CSS**

```
.loginRectangle {
    float: right;
    width:564px;
    height:100%;
    background-image:url(../img/rectangle.png);
    text-align: center;
    font-size: 28px;
}

.innerRect {
    float: right;
    width: 564px;
    height:100%;
}

.settingsHelp {
    position: absolute;
    bottom: 10px;
    right:10px;
    text-align:right;
}
```

Comment: Yes, Javascript and it is expected that you at least attempt to code this for yourself. Stack Overflow is not a code writing service. I would suggest that you do some additional research, either via Google or by searching SO, make an attempt and. if you still have trouble, come back with **your code** and explain what you have tried and why it did not work.

Comment: You could add a class on click with JavaScript

Comment: Are you arresting the submit with jQuery/JS? Otherwise the page is gone anyway.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Could you not just add the class with an animation?

```
<input type="submit" id="submitButton" />
```

jQuery

```
$(function() {
    $("#submitButton").on('click', function(){
         $("#sliderBox").addclass('slide');
    })
}
```